# Is it possible to download a .txt file and manipulate said file in one endpoint using ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: c#, json, .net, file, flurl

My task is to download a `.txt` file, remove some of the data and save it as `.json`. Currently I use one interface to download a file as `.txt` file and another interface to read all lines of said file, make it into an object and remove what I don't need.

Currently what happens is, that I have to go to download endpoint to get my `.txt` then to edit endpoint to parse and save as `.json`.

This is the filter method:

```
    public void FilterOutInvalidRates(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var targetLocation = @"TargetLocation/";
            var name = File.ReadAllLines(path).First();
            var fileName = name.Substring(0,3);
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(2);

            var model = lines.Select(p => new Rates
            {
                a = p.Split("|")[0],
                b = p.Split("|")[1],
                c = p.Split("|")[2],
                d = p.Split("|")[3],
                e = p.Split("|")[4],
            });

            List<Rates> rates = model.Where(model => IsTheCountryValid(model.Country)).ToList();

            var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rates.ToArray(), Formatting.Indented);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(targetLocation + fileName + ".json", jsonString);

            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Unable to read file:" + path.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And this is the download service:

```
    public async void DownloadRatesTxtFile(string uri, string outputPath, int number)
    {
        var policy = BuildRetryPolicy();
        var path = await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => uri
        .DownloadFileAsync(outputPath, @"CurrencyRate" + number + ".txt"));
    }
```

This is the controller implementation - I know it's not ideal, if I could do it all in one endpoint or a different architecture I could get rid of a ton of code. The issue is, that before the endpoint returns OK I am not able to manipulate the files in any way or read them.

```
    [HttpGet("download")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download()
    {
        var fileCounter = 1;
        var outputPath2 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Data/";
        var outputPath = @"TargetLocation/";
        DateTime begindate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/07/2022");
        DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime("5/07/2022");
        
        while (begindate < enddate)
        {
            if (begindate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                begindate = begindate.AddDays(2);
            }
            _exchangeRateConnector.DownloadRatesTxtFile(_exchangeRateConnector.GenerateRatesUrl(begindate), outputPath2, fileCounter);
            begindate = begindate.AddDays(1);
            fileCounter++;
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet("edit")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit()
    {
        var outputPath2 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Data/";
        var outputPath = @"TargetLocation/";
        var fileCount = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(outputPath2, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                         select file).Count();

        for (int i = 1; i <= fileCount; i++)
        {
            _exchangeRateRepository.FilterOutInvalidRates(outputPath2 + "CurrencyRate" + i + ".txt");
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Thank you so much for any sort of advice.

Comment: Why can't you just move all the code in `Edit()` into `Download()` just above the line `return Ok();`? Are you getting an error of some kind?

Comment: There's something I think we're missing here: how do you know when to call the `Edit` method i.e. when the `Download` method finished its job? Do you perform a check for the json files?

Comment: Hello, @Xerillio - yes, I have been getting an error - cannot access the file as it's currently being used by another process.  It seemed the obvious solution to put it in one while loop and use the DateTime variable for lot of the things I am having to do manually right now, like naming the .json files.

Comment: @JoshPart right now I am doing it manually - i.e. call download and then edit, where edit essentially runs through every .txt file in /Data folder and does it's thing. I do not perform a check, the task is to get files for a certain time period and it should be around 50 files total. I was experimenting with RedirectToAction etc. but non of it does what I need it to.

The problem seems to be, that while the DownloadRates is using the .txt file, FilterRates can not access it

Comment: @Xerillio when I put it right under the downloader in the while loop it seems to be working somehow...I have been trying this for the past 3 days and have no idea what is happening differently - I used to be able to do it if I refreshed the end point twice, so the .txts would've been already downloaded. This can't be best practice though can it? `_exchangeRateConnector.DownloadRatesTxtFile(_exchangeRateConnector.GenerateRatesUrl(begindate), outputPath2, fileCounter);
  _exchangeRateRepository.FilterOutInvalidRates(outputPath2 + "CurrencyRate" + fileCounter + ".txt");`

Comment: I have just noticed, playing around there is one thing that I might have changed I have changed 
`var outputPath = @"/TargetPath/Data/"; `to 
`var outputPath2 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Data/";`
 Do you think it's possible that this allows for the file to be read and altered in this manner? –

Comment: A different path should not change anything in regards to the error "cannot access the file as it's currently being used by another process". I'm a little unsure if you've solved the problem or not? But if the problem is the file being locked we need to see what the method `uri.DownloadFileAsync(...)` does - it sounds like it doesn't properly release the file.

Comment: Could it be the way the path is accessed? Through AppDomain vs. directly? It does seem to work now, though I honestly have no idea what changed and going to try to dig deeper so I'll keep the question open for a little more. Thank you so much! There 

DownloadFileAsync should be [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=net-6.0) method. Honestly I am not sure what to look for in the docs :/

Comment: @Drinkbeergetmoney I don't think it would cause the issue you describe, but you should take a look at the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0#remarks) of using `WebClient`. It's recommended to use `HttpClient` instead.